# Toast message only in Testing

Tags: android

I am android newbie.

I made a simple program, and I used `Toast` code for checking if variable is correct or not. After finishing test, I have to remove all the `Toast` code to release app. I think there must be more effective and better way to do this.

please help me

thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any Toast in your app aside from you code checking?

Comment: @Seth Hikari   Yes it is..    But I want to listen about your idea

Comment: You could use the regex, if you do well with it to look for Toast.[whatever + debug simular stuff] and remove it that way, but if you mess up... and remove code you did not want to that would suck

Comment: I would not edit the code to remove the Toast or log messages. See my answer for an suggestion.

Comment: OH If you really wanted to keep the Toasts just do a boolean DEBUGORSOMETHING = True then your toasts will say if debug then toast.show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ant, you can have define some parameter like build.debug in build.properties files, you will need to have two different files build_dbg.properties and build_rel.properties.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you.  Is there method to do this without ant? I write and build code in eclipse.

Comment: How about this One..         
    'boolean debug = false;
    String str = "";
    Log.d("TAG",str = "debug");
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("debug"))
        debug = true;"

Answer (score 2):

Use LogCat. You can output values to LogCat output using `Log.d` in your code. You can read detailed information about LogCat and logging here [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

Comment: isn't there a way to see debug message on my android phone?  LogCat is only in PC. isn't it..

Comment: There is the UNIX log on your Android phone, you can find many apps that let you view it just like you see it on Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the `Log` class and redirect everything to `android.Log`.
In your own implementation you can then fire the `Toast`.

You will need to pass the `Context` and maybe execute it on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Log.[vdiwe], you should consider to use [Androlog](http://akquinet.github.com/androlog/). It does the same as the default android Log class, but you can switch it of when you release your app later on.

It also supports some kind of reporting mechanism, which I did not test up to now, but looks promising.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve never bothered with the Log class, because I found that everything written to System.err appears in the Android log regardless.

Comment: Why the downvote? Check it for yourself if you don’t believe me.